# Finding past occurrence

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a set of stock units transacted (ordered by date from old to new).

I want to find the Previous Quantity that was transacted.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
 Date(A) Type(B) Stock(C) Qty(D) PrevQty(E) CumulativeQty(F) 
 2016-01-03 Buy MSFT 100 0 100
 2016-01-04 Buy GOOG 500 0 500
 2016-01-05 Buy MSFT 100 100 200
 2016-01-06 Sell MSFT 100 100 100
```

I can compute CumulativeQty via:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C, C4,A:A, "<=" &A4)
```

**Question:** How do I figure out `PrevQty`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula is designed for your cell E3.

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($C$2:$C2=$C3),$D$2:$D2),0)
```

Basically, it looks for the last occurrence of the 'Stock' in C3. However, that last occurrence would naturally by in C3 itself. Therefore the row in which the formula resides is excluded from the range in which the last occurrence is sought.

The presumption is that your first data are in row 2 in your worksheet.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes way more sense now. Another variation of my previous question, how can I get my PrevQty to show cumulative total prior to today. Date(A) Type(B) Stock(C) Qty(D) PrevQty(E) CumulativeQty(F) 
 2016-01-17 Buy MSFT 100 0 100
 2016-01-23 Buy GOOG 500 0 500
 2016-11-14 Buy MSFT 100 100 200                                                  
 New Row>>>>2016-12-01 Buy MSFT 100 200 300
 2016-12-01 Sell MSFT 100 100 100

Comment: I'm afraid I don't entertain follow-up questions. If your question was answered select the answer that worked for you and ask your next question in another thread. You can do the cumulative total very easily with a simple SUMIF() function using the same technique for excluding the current row from the criteria and sum ranges as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

PrevQty

```
{=index(D:D,match((A4-1)&C4,A:A&C:C,0))}
```

***Update:***
For non-sequential dates, to get the value from the same Stock Name, you'll need to do 2 sorting - 1 date from old to new, 2 stock name from A-Z or Z-A

Leave the first (oldest stock) row empty and start the formula from the second oldest row of that stock name. Plus N/A handling.

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MAX(A$3:A3)&C4,A:A&C:C,0)),0)}
```

Example below: (above formula in cell E4)
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. One slight variation: what if the dates are not  sequential. They can take any value but are in sorted (old to new).  For example: Date(A) Type(B) Stock(C) Qty(D) PrevQty(E) CumulativeQty(F) 
 2016-01-17 Buy MSFT 100 0 100
 2016-01-23 Buy GOOG 500 0 500
 2016-11-14 Buy MSFT 100 100 200
 2016-12-01 Sell MSFT 100 100 100

Comment: And also match returns "#N/A" when no exact match found. Is there a way to return digit 0 instead of "#N/A"?